# Hover over the para should display the same content in jquery

Tags: jquery

Whenever i hover the "p", its should show the content like "duplicate"
and click the "duplicate" to hovered para should be display under the "p"
here i try some thing...

```
<div id="one">
<p>This is para, when i hover i will appear. </p>
<p>This is another, when i hover i will appear. </p>
<h4 id="o"><a href="#one">Duplicate</a></h4>
<div class="tex"></div>
<ul>
</ul>
</div>
```

and jquery is

```
var id = '';
 $("p").hover(function() {
id = $(this).text();
$("#o").show();
},
function() {
$("#o").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
 });

$("#o").click(function() {
 $(id).appendTo("tex");
  });
```

here i did some error. but i dont know that.

Comment: can you please be a bit more descriptive ? i do not understand. on click of "duplicate" where do you want the para to appear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the full answer what you want.

HTML

```
 <div id="one">
 <p>This is para, when i hover i will appear.</p>
 <p>This is another, when i hover i will appear.</p>
 <h4 id="o"><a href="#one">Duplicate</a></h4>
 </div>
```

Here the jquery

```
(function($) {
$.fn.outerHTML = function(s) {
return (s)
? this.before(s).remove()
: $('<p>').append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
}
})(jQuery);

var is, id = '';
$("p").live({
    mouseover: function() {
   is = $(this);
    id = $(this).outerHTML();
     $("#o").insertBefore(is).show();
  },
  mouseout: function() {
    $("#o").delay(2500).fadeOut("slow");
  }
});
$("#o").click(function() {
 $(is).after(id);
});
```

Here the demo : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9vg8u/17/)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `id` as selector, that is not right.

```
var txt = '';
$("p").hover(function () {
    txt = $(this).text();
    $("#o").show();
},

function () {
    $("#o").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
});

$("#o").click(function () {
    $('.tex').append(txt);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.tex').append(id);
```

instead of

```
$(id).appendTo("tex");
```

You are trying to convert your text into a jquery object `$(id)`.. What you want to do is append the text to your element with class=tex

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/9vg8u/5/